# Kubernetes fix gke-metrics-agent stuck in terminating state on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

GKE had an outage about 2 days ago in their London datacentre (https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/20013), since which time one of my nodes has been acting up. I've had to manually terminate a number of pods running on it and I'm having issues with a couple of sites, I assume due to their liveness checks failing temporarily which might have something to do with the below error in `gke-metrics-agent`?

Looking at the system pods I can see one instance of `gke-metrics-agent` is stuck in a terminating state and has been since last night:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

reports:

```
...
gke-metrics-agent-k47g8                                     0/1     Terminating   0          32d
gke-metrics-agent-knr9h                                     1/1     Running       0          31h
gke-metrics-agent-vqkpw                                     1/1     Running       0          32d
...
```

I've looked at the describe output for the pod but can't see anything that helps me understand what it needs done:

```
kubectl describe pod gke-metrics-agent-k47g8 -n kube-system
```

```
Name:                      gke-metrics-agent-k47g8
Namespace:                 kube-system
Priority:                  2000001000
Priority Class Name:       system-node-critical
Node:                      <node-name>/<IP>
Start Time:                Mon, 09 Nov 2020 03:41:14 +0000
Labels:                    component=gke-metrics-agent
                           controller-revision-hash=f8c5b8bfb
                           k8s-app=gke-metrics-agent
                           pod-template-generation=4
Annotations:               components.gke.io/component-name: gke-metrics-agent
                           components.gke.io/component-version: 0.27.1
                           configHash: <config-hash>
Status:                    Terminating (lasts 15h)
Termination Grace Period:  30s
IP:                        <IP>
IPs:
  IP:           <IP>
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/gke-metrics-agent
Containers:
  gke-metrics-agent:
    Container ID:  docker://<id>
    Image:         gcr.io/gke-release/gke-metrics-agent:0.1.3-gke.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/gke-release/gke-metrics-agent@sha256:<hash>
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /otelsvc
      --config=/conf/gke-metrics-agent-config.yaml
      --metrics-level=NONE
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 09 Nov 2020 03:41:17 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 10 Dec 2020 21:16:50 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     3m
      memory:  50Mi
    Environment:
      NODE_NAME:       (v1:spec.nodeName)
      POD_NAME:       gke-metrics-agent-k47g8 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  kube-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      KUBELET_HOST:   127.0.0.1
      ARG1:           ${1}
      ARG2:           ${2}
    Mounts:
      /conf from gke-metrics-agent-config-vol (rw)
      /etc/ssl/certs from ssl-certs (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from gke-metrics-agent-token-cn6ss (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  gke-metrics-agent-config-vol:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      gke-metrics-agent-conf
    Optional:  false
  ssl-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/ssl/certs
    HostPathType:
  gke-metrics-agent-token-cn6ss:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  gke-metrics-agent-token-cn6ss
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     :NoExecute
                 :NoSchedule
                 components.gke.io/gke-managed-components
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Events:          <none>
```

I'm not used to having to work on the system pods, in the past my experience troubleshooting issues often falls back on force deleting them when all else fails:

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> -n <ns> --grace-period=0 --force
```

My concern is I don't fully understand what this might do for a system pod and was hoping someone with expertise could advise on a sensible way forward?

I'm also looking at draining this node so Kubernetes can rebuild a new one. Would this potentially be the easiest way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this I found the pod that was experiencing the issues with `gke-metrics-agent` became even less stable as the day went on.

I, therefore, had to drain it. The resources it was running are now on new nodes which are working as expected and all system pods are running as expected (including `gke-metrics-agent`).

Prior to draining this node I ensured, **Pod Disruption Budgets** were in place as a number of services run on 1 or 2 instances:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/

This meant I could run:

```
kubectl drain <node-name>
```

The deployments then ensured they had enough live pods prior to the bad node being taken offline and seems to have avoided any downtime.